# Is it possible to have a Shared Dependency in all my android studio projects?

Tags: android, gradle

Every time I create an android project, I have to add for example "navigation library" or some other ones,Is it possible to make it such the desired dependency is already included in my every project? the reason I want this is because adding and downloading these libraries are hard for me due to some IP limitations.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of dependency is it? A .jar library?

Comment: for example this: dependencies {
  val nav_version = "2.4.2"

  // Java language implementation
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version")
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version")

  // Kotlin
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
  implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")

}

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template project like the one you get to choose when creating new projects in android studio. Android Studio does not have this built-in, you have to look for workarounds.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623926/how-do-i-create-custom-project-templates-to-android-studio-3-6-or-above)

Template selection screen
[image: Templete selection screen]